# What is the date displayed for the question mark?

Tags: rebus, time, outer-space

Someone sent me these images. It's about the Moon for some reason. Anyways, here are the images:

[image]

[image]

And also that someone gave me a bonus:

[image]

Comment: Is this in fact two good puzzles?

Comment: Is this a puzzle someone else actually sent you, or is that bit just for a story?

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is

> 04/22/2016 as the first image shows a crescent and gradually into a full moon.

I couldn't quite understand the second one

For the second one I think I am close but it doesn't make sense

> Put the Dine (D in E) in a zone (last letter 'z'  o on e but it will result in oone anyways) z ...... and it continues.